# Weird issue with platypus (makes .app packages from scripts)

Tags: python, osx-mountain-lion, platypus

I wrote myself a small Python script that I want to use to automatically do things with certain types of files; as such, I want to create an `.app` out of it so that I can set certain files to be opened with it automatically.

So I looked around and found Platypus which seems to do what I need.

However, weirdly it doesn't work. Specifically, it does not seem to be finding the right python interpreter. I set it up as follows:

[image]

I.e., the script type is `env` so it should just read the top line of the file like the shell does.

In `magic.py`, the top line is `#!/usr/bin/env python2.7`.

Now, when I run the shell script on the command line (that is, `~/devel/magic.py whatever`), everything works fine. But when I run the app, it errors with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jan/Dropbox/devel/Magic.app/Contents/Resources/script", line 8, in <module>
    from bencode import *
ImportError: No module named bencode
```

The same import works just fine when running it from the command line, so I'm thinking it's using the wrong interpreter somehow. How can I fix or debug this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to import from `bencode` module but you didn't add it in the application's bundled resources. Either drag it to the list of included files and export again or just copy it to the resources folder in the package's contents.

Comment: but that's a package installed on the system, shouldn't it just find it normally?

Comment: Is it? I just tried the same thing with `numpy` and it worked.

Comment: I just copied the entire package from `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/etc/etc/` and it worked, but that's a very stupid design, why do you need to copy packages which are installed system-wide?

Comment: I guess I'll accept since this works, though I don't get why this should be necessary

Comment: You shouldn't have to if its in `site-packages`... I meant that I did `import numpy`, did some `numpy.array` work, and printed it. I suppose the advantage is that the app is more portable now.